# SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in R's loop

Tags: r, loops, spatial

I have several saved SpatialPolygonsDataFrame RData files.
I'd like use them in loop:

```
polygons <- c('A','B','C','D')
for (polygon_name in polygons) {
    kml.path <- paste("~/KML/",polygon_name,".kml.RData",sep="")
    kml <- load(kml.path)

    proj4string(coordinate.anagog) <- proj4string(kml)
    points.in.polygons.output <- over(coordinate.anagog, kml)}
```

But when I load saved RData file to `kml` it has been saved like string (name of saved object)
So when I run `print(kml)` I see string

> [1]"A.kml"

instead SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

How I can solve it?

Comment: It is probably better to work with RDS rather than RData files - you can then load to a different variable name than the one it was saved under (`load` restores the original name).  Use `saveRDS` and `readRDS`.

Comment: ...Or, if `kml` is returning the name of the saved df, just add a line `kml<-get(kml)` after the load, to assign the name `kml` to the variable whose name is returned from the `load`.

Comment: OK, I get it, thank you, @Andrew Gustar